# Switching puzzle identification

Tags: puzzle-identification

I'm looking for the name of a puzzle where the goal is to activate (or deactivate) a set of buttons.

If you activate a button, it switches the state of this button and of its neighbour.

Say you start in this situation

```
0 0 0
0   0
0 0 0
```

And you activate the top left button, then you end up in this state.

```
1 1 0
1   0
0 0 0
```

If you activate the middle left button, it switches it and its neighbour (so it switches the whole left column). Result states follows :

```
0 1 0
0   0
1 0 0
```

I understand it is a simple permutation game, but I'd like to know if it has a special name. It's often encountered in video games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One name I often hear is a [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_%28game%29) puzzle.

Comment: It could be Merlin as well. was reading the link that charfellow provided and it states that